# Selenium driver.page_source InvalidArgumentException

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I am having very weird behavior with Selenium, my Python web scraping script was working previous week, but today it does not.

URL I am scraping is Google maps reviews in Lithuanian language:

```
driver.get('https://www.google.com/maps/place/Depo/@54.9388288,23.8977024,12z/data=!4m7!3m6!1s0x46dd9100a1414c23:0x3ab761cf0d216f62!8m2!3d54.7417742!4d25.225869!9m1!1b1')
```

Using `BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser')` raises me an error:

```
"InvalidArgumentException: Message: unexpected end of hex escape at line 1 column 721856"
```

The Error is being raised by `"self.execute(Command.GET_PAGE_SOURCE)['value']"`, but what is interesting is that it raises the error only when I scroll down for more reviews. It does work if I do not scroll and scrape only several top comments using:

```
reviews = BeautifulSoup(driver.page_source, 'html.parser').find_all('div', class_ = 'jftiEf fontBodyMedium') 
for result in reviews[:-1]:
    print(result.find('span', class_='wiI7pd').text)
```

I am using the latest Selenium version ('4.4.3') and firefox webdriver.
Anyone have any ideas what to do, how to scrape all reviews.
Thank you.

Comment: The code you provided here is running without any problems in chrome. How are you scrolling through all data?

Comment: @Anjaan I find scrollable div with "WebDriverWait(driver, 20).until(EC.visibility_of_element_located((By.XPATH, "//div[@class='m6QErb']")))" and later send multiple END keys wiht "scrollable_div.send_keys(Keys.END)". But I tried manual scroll with mouse and still received error. I shall try other browsers.

Comment: It's working on Chrome, so you may have to try it with a different browser. Or instead of XPath you may try it with ID or Class if availble.

Comment: @Anjaan I can confirm it's problem with FireFox. I tried Chrome and also Edge and both work as expected. Thank you.

Comment: @Anjaan you should post your comment as an answer (with a minimal reproducible code, to demonstrate the viability of your solution), and then the OP should mark your answer as accepted. You did the work, you deserve recognition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is working fine on Chrome and you may check it on other browsers as well. Sometimes the issue may be caused by cache or cookies you may want to try removing them for a change. If not you should change the browser.